# CSS: Make an image come to the top of a div

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
<div id="why">
    <div class="gallery clearfix">
        <img src="images/why-bg.png" class="background-why">
        <div class="gallery-inner">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-inner">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-inner">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

MY CSS:

```
#why{
  height: 100%;
}
#why .gallery{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#why .background-why{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

I want the `.background-why` to come over the `.gallery`. But it stay under the `.gallery` with my code. I think this image will help you to understand what I am expecting
[image]

Comment: add jsfiddle or code snippet please.

Comment: Can you not use z-indeX?

Comment: Could you not just put the `img` tag after the `div` tags in the code (or use z-index)?  Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: if your goal is to put some text in your `.gallery-inner` and want to display them, maybe what you want is to add `.galllery-inner{backgrond-color:transparent}`. or you may prefer to add `.gallery{background-image:url(images/why-bg.png);bacgkground-repeat:no-repeat;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the z-index property for your .background-why class.

Your css should look like this:

```
#why{
  height: 100%;
}
#why .gallery{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#why .background-why{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Z-index is your answer. Set the z-index of the top element higher than your background ones

```
#why{
  height: 100%;
}
#why .gallery{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
#why .background-why{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index:

```
#why .background-why{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  z-index:1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs:

1) If you wish that .background-why to be permanently over the .gallery-inner (that whole area is .gallery-inner) - **jsfiddle.net/bw6ecbuy/1/**

2) If you want the .background-why to come over the .gallery-inner on hover than: **jsfiddle.net/a8yszLsf/2/**

Leave a comment if I got this wrong.